# How to cut the csv data into equal parts using python and panda

Tags: pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook

I want to cut my CSV file equal parts and then plot the graph separately then one graph to overlap all the graph into one graph.

Comment: welcome to Stackoverflow!. Could you show an example of your dataframe? And your expected outputs?

Comment: How many chunks do you want?

Comment: i have csv file and cut it into four parts then overlap with each other and then i need to find out the average graph by the four plot into one graph.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('filepath')

n_splits = 4
dfs = []

for x in range(n_splits):
    dfs.append(df[x*int(len(df)/n_splits):(x+1)*int(len(df)/n_splits)])

fig = plt.figure()

for frame in dfs:
    plt.plot(frame['col1'], frame['col2'])

plt.show()
```

But not knowing how you want to split or what the dataframe looks like makes it harder to provide a more relevant answer.

Comment: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 6: invalid start byte
get this error

Comment: yes it's unable to read your csv because of some invalid characters. Try df = pd.read_csv('filepath',encoding = "ISO-8859-1")

Comment: I got four csv file now i need to plot into one graph what should i do.

Comment: I've just answered that for you. See the code above

Comment: You need to provide examples of the dataframe and the code you are currently working with